# Asyncio combine output of multiple API calls into one variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm doing few API calls towards Azure REST API using asyncio and aiohttp, the problem is output of each API call which is written to variable is replacing the output of the previous call. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
async def TM_main(session, urlTMs):
    async with session.get(urlTMs) as resp:
        getTMs = await resp.json()
        return getTMs
```

```
async def TrafficManagers():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headerAuth,connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
            tasks = []
            for subscription in subscriptions['value']:
                urlTMs = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'+subscription['subscriptionId']+'/providers/Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles?api-version=2018-04-01&$top=2000'
                tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(TM_main(session,urlTMs)))
            getTMs = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...the problem is output of each API call which is written to
> variable is replacing the output of the previous call"

No it's not. `await`ing the `gather()` coroutine would return a list of all values returned by passed awaitable objects.

Your setup looks ok to me. For creating tasks [it's recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) to use `create_task()` instead of `ensure_future()`:

> Important See also the `create_task()` function which is the preferred
> way for creating new Tasks.

Comment: ok I don't know how I did it, but you are right, this stuff is really in there 0.o